# TSQL - Sum of Top 3 records of multiple teams

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, nested

I am trying to generate a TSQL query that will take the top 3 scores (out of about 50) for a group of teams, sum the total of just those 3 scores and give me a result set that has just the name of the team, and that total score ordered by the score descending.  I'm pretty sure it is a nested query - but for the life of me can't get it to work!
Here are the specifics, there is only 1 table involved....

`table = comp_lineup` (this table holds a separate record for each athlete in a match)

```
* athlete
* team
* score
```

There are many athletes to a match - each one belongs to a team.

Example:

```
id     athlete     team     score<br>
1      1           1        24<br>
2      2           1        23<br>
3      3           2        21<br>
4      4           2        25<br>
5      5           1        20<br>
```

Thank You!

Comment: do you want to take the top 3 score per team or just the top 3 scores overall?

Comment: sum of the Top 3 scores per team. Nope - not homework...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a subquery, which I often put in a CTE instead just for clarity. The trick is the use of the rank() function.

```
;with RankedScores as (
    select
        id,
        athlete,
        team,
        score,
        rank() over (partition by team order by score desc) ScoreRank
    from
        @scores
)
select
    Team,
    sum(Score) TotalScore
from
    RankedScores
where
    ScoreRank <= 3
group by
    team
order by
    TotalScore desc
```

Comment: I should add that this might not give you exactly what you want if a team has multiple scores of the same value. In that case you might want to use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Comment: I think we're on the right track - I'm getting the teams in the correct order, but it won't display the totalScore...?  Thank You!

Comment: Did you not use my sql? The output includes team and total score.

Comment: I did...I have it running now...I'm just trying to figure out how to make the score  an aggregate, like (round1 + round2) as score.

Comment: OK - here's where I'm at - it doesn't like it cause it can't find "score"...with RankedScores as (
    select
        id,
        team,
        isnull(round1,0) + isnull(round2,0) as score,
        rank() over (partition by team order by score desc) ScoreRank
    from
        comp_lineup
where event_id = 436
)
select
    Team,
    sum(isnull(round1,0) + isnull(round2,0)) TotalScore
from
    RankedScores
where
    ScoreRank <= 3
group by
    team
order by
    TotalScore desc

Comment: Solved, Thank You JC.

Answer (score 0):

To get the top n value for every group of data a query template is

```
Select group_value, sum(value) total_value
From   mytable ext
Where  id in (Select   top *n* id 
              From     mytable sub 
              Where    ext.group_value = sub.group_value 
              Order By value desc)
Group By group_value
```

The subquery retrieve only the ID of the valid data for the current group_value, the connection between the two dataset is the `Where ext.group_value = sub.group_value` part,  the WHERE in the main query is used to mask every other ID, like a cursor.

For the specific question the template became

```
Select team, sum(score) total_score
From   mytable ext
Where  id in (Select   top 3 id 
              From     mytable sub 
              Where    ext.team = sub.team 
              Order By score desc)
Group By team
Order By sum(score) Desc
```

with the added Order By in the main query for the descending total score